# Indexing of Triples in MarkLogic

Tags: marklogic

**We do not have to store all possible permutation of triples entires in the index. How many should we store and why?**

Comment: I don't know why you're trying to do permutations. Just create your triples (with a sensible subject, predicate, and object) and let MarkLogic do the work to figure out how to best use them in queries. You'll never need to do permutations.

Comment: Maybe you could elaborate a bit more on what you mean with 'permutations'?